# Logparser and powershell with multiple logfiles in a foreach-object loop

Tags: powershell, for-loop, logparser

So I'm trying to write a powershell script that will go through a folder full of .evtx files, send out each one via syslog, then append ".done" to the filename of the .evtx file after doing so.

The thing is, I'm not quite sure how to reference the current log file I am on within the Foreach-Object loop.

Hopefully the following code will explain my dillema.

```
# begin foreach loop
Get-ChildItem $evtxfolder -Filter *.evtx | `
Foreach-Object {
$LPARGS = ("-i:evt", "-o:syslog", "SELECT STRCAT(`' evt-Time: `', TO_STRING(TimeGenerated, `'dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss`')),EventID,SourceName,ComputerName,Message INTO $SERVER FROM $CURRENTOBJECT") #obviously, this won't work.
$LOGPARSER = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Logparser 2.2\logparser.exe"
$LP = Start-Process -FilePath $LOGPARSER -ArgumentList $LPARGS -Wait -Passthru -NoNewWindow
$LP.WaitForExit() # wait for logs to finish
```

If you look in $LPARGS, you'll see that I put $SERVER and $CURRENTOBJECT. Obviously, the way I have it now will not work, but obviously, that won't work. So basically, I'm trying to put the variable $SERVER (passed in as a parameter) into the arguments for logparser, and reference whatever current event log it is working on to put in the "FROM" statement so that it knows to work on one .evtx file at a time. What would be the proper way to do this?

An example of the INTO FROM statement:

```
..snippet..
SourceName,ComputerName,Message INTO @192.168.56.30 FROM 'C:\Eventlogs\20131125.evtx'"
```

Of course, 'C:\Eventlogs\20131125.evtx' would change as it goes through the contents of the directory.

Comment: Our powershell version is 2.

Comment: Which is the final ps1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$server` is defined outside your script above it will be available inside your string for $LPARGS.  As for the $CURRENTOBJECT, that would be `$_`.  In this case, it will be a FileInfo object.  It is likely you want the Name property e.g. `$($_.Name)`.

Comment: Alright, so I'm then I should change $SERVER to $($_.SERVER)? Within $LPARGS? That still leaves the question of what to do with $CURRENTOBJECT

Comment: `$_` represents each of the files you've retrieved with `Get-ChildItem $evtxfolder -Filter *.evtx` and sent down the pipeline.  All you need to do for `$SERVER` is set it before the script that iterates the evtx files e.g. `$SERVER = 'servername'`.

Comment: So $CURRENTOBJECT should be $($_.) then? I'm not 100% sure I understand.

Comment: Perhaps you should write out an example of what you would like `INTO ??? FROM ????` to be after expanding variables for one of the files.

Comment: Noted, I have added it in the question. Basically, the directory would contain a number of .evtx files, it just has to loop through it to finish all of them. I suppose I am looking for the right things to put in place of $SERVER (which we have determined to be $($_.SERVER)) and $CURRENTOBJECT (which would be the full path to whatever .evtx file the loop currently is on).

Comment: Full path to the EVTX is easy - `$($_.Fullname)`.  I can't tell you what to use for `$SERVER` as I've never used LogParser but I can tell you that it won't be `$($_.Server)`.  There is no `Server` property on a FileInfo object.

Comment: Hmm. I mean, I've already declared what the value of $SERVER earlier in the script, it's just a matter of figuring out how to put it in the arguments for logparser as well.

Comment: Then all you need to do is reference the variable in the double quoted string "...  ${SERVER} ...".